# GPT disk unaccessible lost HFS+ partitions

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, gpt, hfs+, gdisk

MBP early 2011 running OSX 10.11.6
3TB Seagate external HDD

My Seagate had all (not sure how many) HFS+ partitions working ok until one day it stopped mounting.

currently listed as /dev/disk3 and gdisk finds no partitions:

```
Type device filename, or press <Enter> to exit: /dev/disk3
Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries.

ommand (? for help): p
Disk /dev/disk3: 8089950 sectors, 3.9 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 9FBCC48E-F444-4824-8A65-37982CD1297B
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 8089916
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 8089883 sectors (3.9 GiB)

Disk size is 8089950 sectors (3.9 GiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0x00000000
MBR partitions:

Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status      Code
   1                     1      8089949   primary     0xEE
```

Verifying only scans what it can find:

```
No problems found. 8089883 free sectors (3.9 GiB) available in 1
segments, the largest of which is 8089883 (3.9 GiB) in size.
```

I tried a hexdump:

```
MBP3OS:~ tivadark$ sudo dd if=/dev/disk3 bs=512 count=1 | hexdump -C
Password:
dd: /dev/disk3: Input/output error
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes transferred in 0.151342 secs (0 bytes/sec)
```

I am afraid to use the gdisk r options. Can someone advise how I can go about restoring my partitions?

Comment: You've got backups, right? :( - It looks like the drive is entirely dead.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the drive sounds like it's died. An input/output error means that the data from the drive isn't making sense, or there simply isn't any data coming back.

You can try the various 'fixes' listed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device) however these are for all recovering data, not 'fixing' the drive - I very much doubt you'll be able to fix the drive.

Comment: thx for the input djsmiley2k

do you think TestDisk or DDrescue might be able to help or should I just re-initialise HFS+/verify disk and then try DataRescue?
Perhaps mount the drive via SATA?

Comment: ddrescue or testdisk both might help. I'd run ddrescue first and get an image of the disk if you can. However, if dd itself is just getting input/output error right from the start then you might not be able to get anything off it without trying to swap out the circuit board.